# run php script from command-line only showing code

Tags: php

I using windows 10 creator and want to make a sample of php for test, but when run from commandline, it only showing the code

```
G:\xampp\htdocs\chat-box>php -v
PHP 5.6.30 (cli) (built: Jan 18 2017 19:48:22)
Copyright (c) 1997-2016 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.6.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2016 Zend Technologies

G:\xampp\htdocs\chat-box>php bin\chat_server.php
use Ratchet\Server\IoServer;
use Ratchet\Http\HttpServer;
use Ratchet\WebSocket\WsServer;
use ChatWebSocket\Chat;

require dirname(__DIR__) . '/vendor/autoload.php';

$server = IoServer::factory(
    new HttpServer(
        new WsServer(
            new Chat()
        )
    ),
    8080
);
print("Hello WebSocket!")
$server->run();
G:\xampp\htdocs\chat-box>
```

I have never get this before.
Any problem with my command?

Comment: What is the permissions on the chat_server.php file?

Comment: Does chat_server.php have the opening `<?php`

Comment: oh my bad, I forget this <?php. I'm wondering why notepad++ not detect that is PHP script.. Thank you mkaatman

Answer (score 6):

You are missing the opening `<?php` tag.